# How do i decode a base64url on next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

So i am working on sign in with google auth. when i hit the API i am re-routed to google to add my email and password once that is done i am re-routed from my backend to a temporary auth page. here the user details is sent as a token attached on the url. i have been able to console.log the token but i need to decode from base64url and convert it to proper json object then. reroute that user to his/her dashboard using the gotten details.

```
import React from 'react'
import style from '../../styles/dashboard/authentication.module.css'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';

export default function Authentication() {

  const router = useRouter();
  let token = router.query;

  token = JSON.parse(atob(Base64));

  console.log(token)

  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
        <div>
            <img src={"/svg/ellipsis.svg"}  width={'46px'} halt="google" />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```